# jQuery namespace variable undeclared

Tags: jquery, undeclared-identifier

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function LoadWord(currentLanguage, currentId, isBadWord)
{
    var filePath, badFilePath;
    switch(currentLanguage) {
        case 'spanish':
                filePath = 'data/spanish.xml';
                badFilePath = 'data/badSpanish.xml';
            break;
        case 'catalan':
                filePath = 'data/catalan.xml';
                badFilePath = 'data/badCatalan.xml';
            break;

        default: return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: filePath,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('word').each(function(){
                if($(this).find('id').text() == $.myNameSpace.cImgId)
                {
                    $.myNameSpace.currentWord = $(this).attr('name');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: badFilePath,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {
                            $(xml).find('word').each(function(){
                                for(index = 0; index < 3; index++)
                                {
                                    if($(this).find('id').text() == $.myNameSpace.badWordsIds[index])
                                    {
                                        $.myNameSpace.badWords[index] = $(this).attr('name');
                                    }
                                }
                                UpdateWords();
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(x) { alert(x.responceText); }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(x) { alert(x.responceText); }
    });
}

function UpdateWords()
{
    var languageWordPos = randomFromTo(1, 4);
    var index = 1;
    var badWordsIndex = 0;

    while (index < 5) {
        if (index == languageWordPos ) {
            SetTextToButton(index, $.myNameSpace.currentWord);
        }
        else {
            SetTextToButton(index, $.myNameSpace.badWords[badWordsIndex]);
            badWordsIndex++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    LoadUserOwnWord($.myNameSpace.lang, $.myNameSpace.cImgId);
}

function SetTextToButton(index, text)
{
    console.log("SetTextToButton");
    switch(index)
    {
        case 1:
            $('#Word1').html(text);
        break;
        case 2:
            $('#Word2').html(text);
        break;
        case 3:
            $('#Word3').html(text);
        break;
        case 4:
            $('#Word4').html(text);
        break;
        default: return;
    }
}
```

I declare `$.myNameSpace.badWords` in this line:

```
$.myNameSpace.badWords[index] = $(this).attr('name');
```

This line is declared inside second ajax call sucess function.

When I try to get a value from `$.myNameSpace.badWords` here:

```
SetTextToButton(index, $.myNameSpace.badWords[badWordsIndex]);
```

I get an undeclared variable. This line is inside `UpdateWords()` function.

I'm debugging with FireBug and I can't see `BadWords` on `$.myNameSpace` variable.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `index < 3;` `index < 5` your loop is bigger in `UpdateWords`

Comment: @jen: SetTextToButton is now on my question.

Comment: @Raynos: this is not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that I can't use an Array it is not initialized.

I can do this inside success function:

```
$.myNameSpace.badWords = new Array(3);
```

And it will be available to any other function.

Answer (score 2):

you are declaring the variable inside the ajax call so it is local to that function, you will have to just instantiate the variable outside of the ajax call so it is available to the other function.